# How to replace "$" using sed command?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

lets say I have some text `A B $ D E` in a file and I want to replace $ with y. how can we?

I tried `sed 's/$/y' filename > filename1`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `$` is a [special character in regular expressions](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html).

Try using `sed 's/\$/y/' filename > filename1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**alternative**

use of class character

```
sed 's/[$]/y/' YourFile
```

use of translation (change all $ of the lines in scope)

```
sed 'y/$/y/' YourFile
```